# Impossible to authorise a script in Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

I'm just trying to authorise a script in Google, I have this error message at the end: "Something went wrong. Please try again."

Here are the screenshots:

[image: Error message when trying to authorise a script]

I tried to use another Google account but I get the same result. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to use a different browser? or a different network?

Comment: Try a different browser?

Comment: Hi thx for your answers. What is quite funny is that I tried on Firefox and it worked… also tried with Chrome in an incognito tab and it seems to work as well…

Comment: @SebMainguet, I added some information that might help you as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the block pop-ups inside Safari by default. I think if you allow the pop-ups for Apps script in Safari that will fix the issue. You can see the steps on how to do so in the following the steps [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/block-pop-ups-sfri40696/mac)

Comment: Thx ! Initially I was on Chrome and not on Safari, but you may be right, this could be a problem with the browser (cookies, cache… I don't know… but I'll investigate there…).